# Ayuda para consulta con Linq y group by

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo una lista de registros donde algunos se repiten en el tiempo.

El campo "Fecha" determina el momento del tiempo en el que el registro es creado.

Necesito hacer una consulta con Linq que me filtre los registros cuya fecha es anterior o igual a la del parámetro, pero que me agrupe por el campo "ClienteId" y me devuelva el más reciente de los registros agrupados.

Pongo algo de código:

```
public class Registro
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int ClienteId {get; set;}
    public DateTime Fecha {get; set;}
    public string Reg {get; set;}
}

List<Registro> lista = new List<Registro>()
{
    new Registro() {Id = 1, ClienteId = 1, Fecha = new DateTime(2019, 04, 01, 09, 55, 00), Reg = "R1"},
    new Registro() {Id = 2, ClienteId = 1, Fecha = new DateTime(2020, 01, 14, 09, 59, 00), Reg = "R2"},
    new Registro() {Id = 3, ClienteId = 1, Fecha = new DateTime(2020, 04, 10, 10, 20, 00), Reg = "R3"},
    new Registro() {Id = 4, ClienteId = 2, Fecha = new DateTime(2019, 04, 25, 12, 00, 00), Reg = "R1"},
    new Registro() {Id = 5, ClienteId = 3, Fecha = new DateTime(2020, 05, 14, 11, 15, 00), Reg = "R1"},
};

DateTime fechaTest = new DateTime(2020, 01, 14, 10, 00, 00);

/* Con ese valor de fechaTest, la consulta debería
*  dar como resultado los registros con Id 2 y 4
*/

var result = lista.Where(x => x.Fecha <= fechaTest).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Vas a tener que llamar al método `GroupBy` de *Linq*, y agrupar por `ClienteId`.

```
var result = lista.Where(x => x.Fecha <= fechaTest).ToList();
var groups = result.GroupBy(r => r.ClienteId);

foreach(var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Cliente {group.Key}");
    foreach(var r in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\tRegistro {r.Id}");
    }
}
```

`GroupBy` devolverá un `IEnumerable<>` de `IGrouping<,>`. El primer argumento de tipo del `IGrouping<,>` será `int`, el `ClienteId` y el segundo será de tipo `Registro`.
Los `IGrouping` se pueden iterar,  como en el ejemplo, e iterará sobre los `Registro` agrupados en cada grupo de `ClienteId`.

Para obtener obtener el grupo que contenga el registro con la fecha más reciente, puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
var result = lista.Where(x => x.Fecha <= fechaTest).ToList();
var groups = result.GroupBy(r => r.ClienteId);

DateTime mostRecent = result.Max(r => r.Fecha);
var mostRecentGroup = groups.First(g => g.Any(r => r.Fecha.Equals(mostRecent)));

Console.WriteLine($"Cliente con {nameof(Registro)} más reciente: {mostRecentGroup.Key}");
foreach(var r in mostRecentGroup) 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"\t{nameof(Registro)} {r.Id}");
}
```

Obtengo la fecha más reciente (la máxima) de los registros filtrados y busco aquel grupo que contenga el registro de esa fecha.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Hola VRoxa. Gracias por la ayuda pero, la idea es hacerlo en una sola consulta (si es que es posible).

Comment: No lo es. Puedes escribirlo en una sola línea, si quieres, pero van a haber como mínimo *queries*.